# how to override word press post while creating post in WP admin. add some extra functionality that post stored into WP meta

Tags: wordpress

How can I override a Wordpress post while creating post in WP admin and add some extra functionality to that post stored into WP meta.

Answer (score 0):

With the *save_post* hook you can change the post that was just created or add meta data to it.